# How to commit/push (to git) the modified project settings in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, sourcetree, project-settings

I changed some Project Directories from my project in Visual Studio. How can I push the changes to git and make it applied to others who pulled my update or checked out my branch?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Which files are affected by changing 'project directories'? Are you asking how to push changes to your vcxproj or csproj file?

Comment: I changed the path in Output Directory of my project (project > properties > config properties > general > output directory), when I pushed it to our git, the changes did not apply to the person who pulled my update.

Note: I only pushed the .vcxproj .. Is this wrong?

Comment: So the commit diff shows a change like `<OutDir>changedDir</OutDir>`, and that line is there after pulling as well, right? In that case there is nothing git can do to solve this, as it would mean on the other machine there is something overriding the OutDir property, thereby ignoring any changes you make to it.

Comment: I already fixed it. It happens that Im using different Checkout project and committed the empty changes. 
I have now encountered the <Outdir> when I changed the properties using the correct Clone of the project. Im sorry. :)
But thank you so much :)